# Regexp parse string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string that can look like:

```
2d
1m
5h
```

I want to parse it and get array:

```
[2, 'd']
[1, 'm']
[5, 'h']
```

I wrote the regexp:

```
var r = /^(\d)([mhd])$/;
var res = r.exec("2m");
console.log(res);
```

It outputs: `["2m", "2", "m"]`

As you can see first item is excess.
How to write it properly?

Comment: just 2 chars , use index is ok

Comment: Are all your strings 2 characters, with the first being a number and the second a letter?

Comment: @passion Do you think it will be much faster?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, number and letter, but number can be 2 chars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already are doing it properly. Just need to pick the right part with *slice()*.

```
var r = /^(\d)([mhd])$/;
var res = r.exec("2m").slice(1, 3);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: `str.match(/\d+|[mhd]/g)`

Comment: @AvinashRaj: that only matches first '2'.

Comment: @bitfet did you add g flag?

Comment: @AvinashRaj: did you edited your comment? (I copied and pasted your code without error :LOL:). Anyway, you are also matching undesired inputs. For example, `"2m4d"` will produce `[ '2', 'm', '4', 'd' ]` while it shouldn't match at all.

Comment: if that the case, then your regex also won't work if the input is `12m`

Comment: The question doesn't ask for matching more than a single digit. It asks about the output of regular expression execution so I suppose the given regexp is right and does exactly what user wants to. Altering the original regexp would be a trick but first you need to approach the same results.

In other words, if the user actually are trying to match hours (which I suppose is what you guessed), then it will need to also fix that regular expression. But this is completely another question. In fact, in that scenario your proposal will also match '99' as a possible value.

Answer (score 1):

js regex.exec will give the whole match as the first item of result array.You can use index to get the catch group.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var r = /^(\d)([mhd])$/;
var res = r.exec("2m");
res = res.slice(1,3);
console.log(res);
```

// output ["2", "m"]